# Keyboard shortcut for "Add clip to conversion list" in GoPro Studio?

Tags: video

Cutting videoclips in GoPro studio is pretty easy:

Press `I` for Mark In, `O` for Mark Out and `Space` for pause/continue. Editing a video would be pretty much faster, if a keyboard shortcut could be also used to add a videoclip to the conversion list, instead of clicking the button with mouse.

Is there a shortcut for the "Add clip to a conversion list", or is it possible to somehow make one? The answer can include usage of third-party programs such as Autohotkey etc.

My operating system is Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

If you google GoPro Keyboard Cover there is a skin with all the shortcuts on it - from GoCam Accessories I think it's called.

Edit: Just realised I could paste a link:

http://www.gocamaccessories.com/shop/gopro-studio-keyboard-cover-for-macs/